# Configure shared credentials in Artifactory Maven 3 job

Tags: artifactory, bamboo

Bamboo supports shared credentials.
I would like to use these shared credentials to commit tags to git using the artifactory maven addon.

According to this ticket: https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/BAP-189 it should work.

I do however not know where to configure it.

We are using bamboo 5.14.3.1
Artifactory plugin 2.1.0

Was this feature removed?